# how to name the folder where model images are uploaded

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have model `Hotel` where is `image` and `name` data.

```
class Example(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default="images/default.jpg")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I need to divide the uploaded images into folders that will be named `name` data in `hotel` model, as in the case of dating

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', default="images/default.jpg", blank=True)
```

this picture data is making dated folder where images are going to be saved.

Comment: Override the `save` method for the model to save to the appropriate directory.

Comment: the dates are in-built method and I am interested if there is method for name it like I need

Comment: Yes but you want to include the name in the path, so you'll need to either change the save method or build a function that returns the right  path and set `upload_to=my_directory_path_function_name_without_brackets`